# Excel: Frequency of variables using countif with &

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, countif

I have two excel sheets. I am finding the frequency of variable school IDs from sheet 1 into sheet2. Lets say a student volunteers for some activity at two schools. So there is an &. I want countif to count schools even where there is &

sheet1

```
   A               B
1 Student name   School ID
2 S1              Sch333 & Sch209
3 S2              Sch209
4 S3              Sch333
5 S4              Sch209 & Sch111
6 S5              Sch209
```

sheet2

```
 A             B
1 School ID     Frequency
2 Sch209
3 Sch333
4 Sch111
```

Formula for frequency of school IDs in cell B2 of sheet2

```
 =COUNTIFS('sheet1'!$b:$b,'sheet2'!a2)
```

This ignores the rows where there is `&`. Expected output

```
         A             B
    1 School ID     Frequency
    2 Sch209          4
    3 Sch333          2
    4 Sch111          1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum the counts for the value alone plus before or after " & "

[image]

Comment: Following is simpler `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C,"*"&Sheet2!B2&"*")` and works.

Comment: Indeed, I agree that it will be a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

In `sheet2, B2` array (CSE) formula copied down :

```
=COUNT(SEARCH(A2,'sheet1'!$B$2:$B$100))
```

Remark : Array (CSE) formula to be confirmed by "Ctrl"+"Shift"+"Enter" to enter it.

Answer (score 1):

According to @shrivallabha.redij, you can remplace your formula

```
=COUNTIFS('sheet1'!$b:$b,'sheet2'!a2)
```

by this one:

```
=COUNTIFS('sheet1'!$b:$b,"*" & 'Sheet2'!a2 & "*")
```

Comment: So that would not match Sch20 with Sch209 ?